# Python decorator runs during import before function is called

Tags: python, python-decorators

I'm trying to use a decorator `check_wake_server` to check if a remote host is available before before executing a `host_function` that interacts with that host. The issue I'm hitting is that the decorator fires off immediately during import before `host_function` is ever called.

Both `check_wake_server` and `host_function` are top level functions in a file called `foo.py` which doesn't have a main function.

```py
# foo.py

import functools

def check_wake_server(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def host_wrapper(func):
        return func(*args, **kwargs)

    print('Decoration is happening!')  
    # check/wake server logic goes here
    return host_wrapper


@check_wake_server
def host_function(*args, **kwargs):
    # this does nothing
    pass
```

When I fire up my interpreter I get the following:

```py
[1] from foo import host_function

Decoration is happening!
```

`check_wake_server` takes a minute to complete so I want to structure this so `check_wake_server` is only run if `host_function` gets called. Ideally I'd also use a decorator so I can re-use this for multiple functions that interact with the remote host.

Comment: "Python decorator runs during import before function is called" Yes, of *course it does*. That's what a decorator is, it is run *on function definition*, not when the function is called.

Comment: If you want your code to run when the decorated function is _invoked_, put it in `host_wrapper`.

Comment: @Nickolay exactly, and if you only want it to run once then you'll have to implement some caching logic.

Comment: @Nickolay your suggestion solved my issue. I needed to move the code into the wrapper function to get the intended behavior. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Nickolay 's comment got me to the desired behavior:

If I want something to execute only when the decorated function is invoked the code needs to be placed within the wrapper.

So the solution is:

```py
def check_wake_server(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def host_wrapper(func):
        # check/wake server logic goes here
        print('Decoration is happening!')
        return func(*args, **kwargs)  
    return host_wrapper
```